# Convert list values in pandas dataframe to values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with a mix of data types (str, list values, floats):

```
            Property Name 2234.1.1 2234.1.2.1 2234.1.3.1
0        Flash Point (°C)     [-5]        NaN        NaN
1        Flash Point (°C)    [Max]        NaN        NaN
2        Flash Point (°C)    [nan]        NaN        NaN
3        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
4        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
5        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
6        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN       [29]
7        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN      [nan]
8        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN      [nan]
9        Flash Point (°C)      NaN      [159]        NaN
10       Flash Point (°C)      NaN      [nan]        NaN
```

I want to convert all the list values to regular values.

So desired df:

```
            Property Name 2234.1.1 2234.1.2.1 2234.1.3.1
0        Flash Point (°C)       -5        NaN        NaN
1        Flash Point (°C)      Max        NaN        NaN
2        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
3        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
4        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
5        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
6        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        29
7        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
8        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
9        Flash Point (°C)      NaN        159        NaN
10       Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
```

I've tried:

```
for i in df.columns[1:]:
    df[i]=[''.join(map(str,l)) for l in df[i]]
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I assume I shouldn't try looping over the df like that anyway.

Edit: adding code to reproduce the df:

```
{'Property Name': {0: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  1: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  2: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  3: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  4: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  5: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  6: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  7: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  8: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  9: 'Flash Point (°C)',
  10: 'Flash Point (°C)'},
 '2234.1.1': {0: ['-5'],
  1: ['Max'],
  2: [nan],
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan,
  10: nan},
 '2234.1.2.1': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: ['159'],
  10: [nan]},
 '2234.1.3.1': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: ['29'],
  7: [nan],
  8: [nan],
  9: nan,
  10: nan}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that deals with it is `explode`. But just calling explode won't works since columns don't have matching element counts. One way to circumvent that problem is to `stack` the DataFrame, `explode` and `unstack` back:

```py
out = df.stack().explode().unstack()
```

If the lists are singleton lists (as in your example), then another option is to call `explode` in loop:

```py
for c in df.columns:
    df = df.explode(c)
```

Another option could be to use `str` accessor and `assign` in a dict comprehension:

```py
out = df.assign(**{f'{c}':df[c].str[0] for c in df.columns.drop('Property Name')})
```

Output:

```py
       Property Name 2234.1.1 2234.1.2.1 2234.1.3.1
0   Flash Point (°C)       -5        NaN        NaN
1   Flash Point (°C)      Max        NaN        NaN
2   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
3   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
4   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
5   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
6   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN         29
7   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
8   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
9   Flash Point (°C)      NaN        159        NaN
10  Flash Point (°C)      NaN        NaN        NaN
```